# Does entraining gamma oscillations attenuate AD-related pathology in humans?

Tags: alzheimers

According to {1}, entraining gamma  (20-50 Hz) oscillations attenuate AD-related pathology in mice.

{1} also note that:

> Gamma is altered in humans with AD.

which seems to indicate that a similar treatment may  work for humans. However, since they focused on mice, they point out that:

> further
>   study is needed to determine whether it will be therapeutic in human AD.

Does entraining gamma oscillations attenuate AD-related pathology in humans?

---

References:

- {1} Gamma frequency entrainment attenuates amyloid load and modifies microglia. Hannah F. Iaccarino,  Annabelle C. Singer,    Anthony J. Martorell,   Andrii Rudenko, Fan Gao, Tyler Z. Gillingham,   Hansruedi Mathys,   Jinsoo Seo, Oleg Kritskiy,  Fatema Abdurrob, Chinnakkaruppan Adaikkan,  Rebecca G. Canter,  Richard Rueda,  Emery N. Brown, Edward S. Boyden    & Li-Huei Tsai. Nature 540, 230–235 (08 December 2016) doi:10.1038/nature20587 ; http://syntheticneurobiology.org/PDFs/16.12.iaccarino.pdf ; https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v540/n7632/full/nature20587.html